Максимальный квадрат на С
Код проходит 16 из 18 тестов. Проверял на компиляторе, вроде ошибки не заметил. В чем косяк может быть?
В массиве из N элементов (N < 20) типа unsigned long long
найти максимальный из полных квадратов и напечатать его индекс (начиная с нуля).
Если нет ни одного полного квадрата, напечатать -1.
Если максимальных более одного, напечатать индекс первого из них.
Входные данные: стандартный поток ввода, где
на первой строке записано N
на второй строке элементы массива через пробел
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int koren(unsigned long long x) {
unsigned long long root = (unsigned long long) sqrt((long double)x);
if (root * root == x)
    return (1);
else
    return (0);
}

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    unsigned long long nums[20];
    int i = 0;
    int nul = 0;
    int ind = -1;
    unsigned long long c = 0;
    unsigned long long mx = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%llu", &c);
        nums[i] = c;
    }
    for (i = n-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (koren(nums[i])==1 && nums[i]>=mx){
             mx = nums[i];
             ind = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", ind);
    return (0);
}


"Код проходит 16 из 18 тестов" — добавьте значения из тех тестов, которые код не проходит. Ещё было бы лучше также добавить ссылку на сами тесты/задачу

В том то и дело, что никак не узнать

А ссылка-то есть?

Если sizeof((long double)x) == 8, то размер мантиссы не позволит разместить точный квадрат достаточного большого x и требуется другой алгоритм

Проверяйте квадраты не только для root, но и root±1. Просто хотелось прежде чем совет давать, убедиться, что проблема именно в этом :)

@avp, я прогнал весь диапазон квадратов и их соседей. Работает.

@Harry, я прогнал весь диапазон квадратов и их соседей. Работает.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, а может быть такое, что root * root дает переполнение и в то же время (root * root == x) == true ? Если да, то может для такого x надо возвращать 0? Т.е. сначала проверить переполнение, а уже потом проверять квадрат.

@avp, там есть переполнение, но оно не приводит к неправильному результату Получается что root*root равен нулю.

@avp, я вообще в этом коде не нашёл очевидных проблем. Всё должно работать. Потому и молчу.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, вы что, перебрали все большие 64-разрядные числа? (мы же не видим исходных данных).

@avp, я перебрал все полные квадраты и их соседей. Для sqrt в IEEE-754 даны такие гарантии, что этого достаточно. Начать с того что тест r * r = x точный. То есть, ошибкой может быть только "дали полный квадрат, да sqrt так налажал, что попал в соседнее целое с корнем из этого полного квадрата". Это невозможно по IEEE-754 (там строгие требования по точности). Кроме того  я проверил все полные квадраты, их всего 2^32.

@Harry, спасибо. Добавил сравнение для root+-1, вышло 18/18

@avp, так как совет Harry помог, мои теории мало чего стоят.

@Harry, можете объяснить, почему +-1, а не, скажем, перебор от +-1 до +-64? Мы же теряем при преобразовании в double 12 младших разрядов

@avp Никогда не задумывался с теоретической точки зрения :) А с практической - всегда боялся получить не, скажем, 12345, а 12344.9999999999 :) Ну, поскольку (x-1)²=x²-2x+1, то, надо понимать, погрешность при преобразовании исходного значения просто меньше 2x-1.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да, я тоже перепроверил для всех полных квадратов на VC++ 2022, все работает... Интересно, почему тогда не работает код из вопроса? Какой-то странный компилятор, специально подсунутый не тот sqrt или что еще?

@Harry, чтобы была ошибка, надо нарушить IEEE-754 (мой любимый). Буду искать конфигурацию компилятора в которой это происходит. Посмотрите /fp:fast. Это тема для отличного вопроса/самоответа "как грамотно написать isqrt(uint64_t)".

@avp, если строго подходить и не предъявлять никаких требований к точности sqrt, то, да, надо смотреть любой диапазон. То есть, значение sqrt воспринимается как догадка, которая проверяется (rr = x), если не совпало, корень ищется другим способом, а значение sqrt используется как хорошее стартовое приближение (если, скажем, метод Ньютона) или стартовая точка для поиска вверх/вниз (если просто линейный поиск, для простоты).

@avp, я размышляю, насколько этично угнать этот вопрос у Harry. Тема интересная, на ruSO можно отыскать огромное количество кривоватых isqrt. Есть и у меня (требует IEEE-754), видел и у Harry (зацикливается).

@StanislavVolodarskiy Это тема для отличного вопроса/самоответа — я в вас верю!! :) Было бы интересно и поучительно...

Кстати, было бы интересно попробовать, пройдет ли вариант (unsigned long long)(sqrt((long double)x)+0.5); или просто с round.

+0.5 выглядит значительно лучше чем простое приведение. Я пока проверить не могу, сперва надо отыскать компилятор/ОС/компьютер на которых текущее решения ошибётся.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, вы про ответ тут? Совершенно нормально. Если еще и Harry даст тут же свой вариант (со своими догадками), то вообще будет шикарно (как в старые времена, когда никто не стеснялся писать много ответов на один вопрос). / А у меня вопрос (к сообществу) -- почему кто-то (видимо не разбирающийся в сути вещей) минусует такие вопросы?
